# Restore Fragments State from back stack manually

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have 4 fragments. When I replace them, I've declared `addToBackStack(null)`. So when I switch the FirstFragment to FourthFragment (or Third, Second - doesn't matter) and then I press Back button, everything is fine. All the view's are already exist.

But when I change Fragment from FourthFragment to FistFragment progromatically (with the help of Bottom Tabs), the State isn't restored and all the views are build again.
I've already tried to use `onSaveInstanceState()`, but it is never being called when I change the fragements. As I've understood, `onSaveInstanceState()` is called only when the Activity is destroyed. In my case, I suppose, the fragments are not destroyed.
But I still need to restore fragment state immediately.

How can I store state of Fragments, when they are being changed between each other?